# react isomorphic and initial data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm creating an isomprphic shop with react and nodejs.
My problem is how to populate my components with initial data on SERVER SIDE.
I know how to populate my home page components with initial data, I fetch data in "/" route and pass them to my components as props. But what about other routes ? 
I can define multiple server side routes but my website isn't SPA anymore.
How can I get bennefits of react router client side routing and initiating data on server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redux can save you some time doing such thing. Or you can calculate state at server and populate it as json to your state store thourgh app's props.

React router does isomorphic easily, but you have to pass your state anyways.

http://redux.js.org/

That's my example index.jsx with react router w/o redux:

```
"use strict";
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { match, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin');
injectTapEventPlugin();

//for dev tools
window.React = React;

const routes = require('./Routes.jsx');

const history = browserHistory;
match({history, routes}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    render(<Router {...renderProps} />, document.getElementById('app'));
})
```

and in Routes.jsx you would find something like:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

const Layout = require("./components/Layout.jsx");
const Login = require("./components/Login.jsx");
const Home = require("./components/Home.jsx");
const NotFound = require("./components/NotFound.jsx");

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following component on the server side for an SPA with react-router, passing in a location prop and the initial state object in ReactDOMServer.renderToString()

ref: [React-Router Server Rendering docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import routes from '../routes';
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
    let store = createStore(reducer, this.props);
    var component;

    match({ routes, location: this.props.location }, function (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
      if (error) {
        component = <p>{error.message}</p>;
      } else if (renderProps) {
        component = <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />;
      } else {
        component = <p>404 not found</p>;
      }
    })

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {component}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real life isomorphic application https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall with all these issues already solved.

Data population issues covered here https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall/blob/master/server/app.js

And here is my blogpost about dealing with isomorphic issues - ["The Pain and the Joy of creating isomorphic apps in ReactJS"](http://blog.koorchik.com/isomorphic-react/)